# Strategy does not enter trades

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

My code is not showing any errors, but when I tried to start it, is not giving any entries, besides that, I want to add a couple of extra filters:

- RSI >50 (when going long)
- SlowEMA > SMA (when going long)
- Close > SlowEMA (when going long)

any suggestions?

```
FastEMA = ema(close,9) // EMA Fast 9 periods
plot(FastEMA,color=color.fuchsia)
SlowEMA = ema(close,26) // EMA Slow 26 periods
plot(SlowEMA,color=color.blue)
plot(sma(close,200),color=color.gray) // SMA 200 periods
rsi = rsi(close, 14) // Relative strength index

// Donchian Channel

length = input(20, minval=1) 
lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)
basis = avg(upper, lower)
u = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#FF9400)
l = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#FF9400)

// Specify crossover conditions

longCondition = crossover(FastEMA, SlowEMA)
shortCondition = crossunder(FastEMA, SlowEMA)

// Execution

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100)
```

Comment: You can try add the `plot(longCondition ? 1 : 0)` into your script and look is there are some bar when plot's value is `1`. Maybe the condition is always false.

Comment: Great idea, thanks @AndreyD

Answer (score 0):

You must add a function to exit the position as well, such as strategy.order, stragegy.close or strategy.exit.

Just as an example, if you would exit 5 bars after entering the trade, you could go with

```
if (barssince(change(strategy.opentrades)) == 5)
    strategy.close("long", comment = "timeout")
```